# How to force object to have a property named over a union type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following types defined

```
type MyUnionType = "propA" | "propB"
type MyType = {
  myProp: MyUnionType
}

type SomeOtherType = MyType & { ... /* other props*/ ... }
```

Now, I would like to enhance `MyType` with something along the lines of

```
type MyType = {
  myProp: MyUnionType,
  [key in MyUnionType]: any // pseudo code
}
```

so that I can use it like this

```
const obj: SomeOtherType = {
  myProp: "propA",
  propA: "some value" // if this is missing, compiler will error
  [...] // some other props
}
```

I played around it a little bit, searched the web, but I didn't come up with any solution.

EDIT: I just removed `string` from `MyUnionType` as requested

Comment: A union of `string` with string literal types is just `string`.  So `MyUnionType` doesn't know anything about `"propA"`; it's just `string`.  Is that really your type?  If `MyUnionType` is a union of string literals, and if you want `MyType` to be such that the value of `myProp` needs to be a key, that can be done as a specific type.  But if `MyUnionType` can literally be any string whatsoever, then this can only be done as a generic constraint.  So it's important to know whether `MyUnionType` really is a union of literals, or if it's just another name for `string`.

Comment: Good catch. I am going to drop that `string` part.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq1z2m) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for. Can you explain your definition for `MyType` in your answer, please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work, you want `MyType` to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) equivalent to:

```
type MyType = {myProp: "propA", propA: any} | {myProp: "probB", propB: any}
```

This has the following desirable behavior:

```
const goodObjA: MyType = {
  myProp: "propA",
  propA: "some value" 
} // okay

const badObjA: MyType = { // error! Property propA is missing
  myProp: "propA",
}

const goodObjB: MyType = {
  myProp: "propB",
  propB: "some value" 
} // okay

const badObjB: MyType = {
  myProp: "propB",
  propA: "oops" // error, unexpected property
}
```

So the only question now is how to generate `MyType` programmatically from `MyUnionType`.  Conceptually we want to take each member `K` in the `MyUnionType` union, and produce a new union of `{ myProp: K } & { [P in K]: any }` (which has a `myProp` property of type `K`, and a `K`-keyed property of type `any`.  That is, we want to *distribute* the `type F<K> = { myProp: K} & { [P in K]: any }` operation across the `MyUnionType` union.

This can be done a few ways, but my approach is to make what's called a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is that you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each `K` in `MyUnionType`, and then immediately [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `MyUnionType`, producing the desired union:

```
type MyType = { [K in MyUnionType]:
  { myProp: K } & { [P in K]: any }
}[MyUnionType]
```

This evaluates to

```
type MyType = 
  ({ myProp: "propA"; } & { propA: any; }) | 
  ({ myProp: "propB"; } & { propB: any; });
```

which is equivalent to the type we want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0QFXNAvFARGAE6pgCC+UAPgcaQEL4CwAUKJLCFh3gN5QBtANJRkiTkjSZsAXQBcrKFH4BbEAAUSYOVBEBfKADJlg9aPFD5UAIaIQUPaz0C4k9NwgzWrAPQ+o7NBwHlB4ABSqGlo6hFoUANwORiZ05Dq2IIl6AJTUUBFQapqkMamMWcn8Zel2WbnebNhQAMqoKhAA8sAAFhBEIXjBTcb8PgBUUKg9fVCpAM5j-o4srADG6HPAUADmqKgAJh0ARgBWZDqt7V29-U18ioVRJbRx+AA0D6nnBHNt0ABu1gANgBXCCUPyiABmAW6yDmogRKnhczE2zeUHWKjAyCBMwA7rigVA+iQiA9IQIAHQ0mRQSG-dqTaZEWZaOZOBrrRCbKBHayHU7fS6dFkDEyQ0moIgAQigxUgRFAbNIZERhRRaIeRWiL1V7wp-mptPp-kZ0CmNxVYA5LGWaw2W12B2OJ3oFz+1z64t42qe2j1YEYHxYSmqPz+UEBoPBpuhsPh6uRc1RiHRmLaOLxrMJQOJUvJobjxqpdIZkctM3mnJWLG5vP5grdHquYruyj9CtKWmDnziMT2Noh-gLGJBiAgAA9IKtgBB9ta+qAaw0GkA)